# ActivityThread.handleStartActivity crash happening in release variant

Tags: android, kotlin

**What is the crash?**

This is specifically happening in release version of the app. I can see the logs in Crashlytics, and this is one of the early crash which happens as soon as the user is opening the app. Also, this happens only uniquely once for very small group of users who all are on Android 12 with Samsung Devices.

**What have I tried so far?**

To be honest, I'm clueless as to why this might be happening. I think the suspect might be a condition on launcher activity that decides whether to `setContentView(binding.root)` or move to next activity. It looks something like this,

```
class LauncherActivity: AppCompatActivity(){
//....

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 installSplashScreen()
 if(viewModel.isLoggedIn()){
   //goToNextActivity()
}else{
   setContentView(binding.root)
  }
 }
}
```

**Stack Trace of Crash**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.graphics.Rect androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.g' on a null object reference in method 'void e.g.H()'
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(ContentFrameLayout.java:93)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1035)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:829)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:536)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:151)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4163)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem happening on the same devices (Samsung Android 12) and can't find what could be wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We refactored our codebase to fully Compose and this went away.